# How to convert a localized string date to Ruby Date object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n, i18n-gem

I have a date which works fine when using it as English

```
> Date.strptime("Aug 02, 2015", "%b %d, %Y")
Sun, 02 Aug 2015
```

However when I use it another language `es`, that doesnt work. E.g.

```
> Date.strptime("ago 02, 2015", "%b %d, %Y")
ArgumentError: invalid date
```

The text strings `ago 02, 2015` itself comes from another service, and I need to standardize it to a particular format such as

```
> I18n.localize(Date.strptime("Aug 02, 2015", "%b %d, %Y"), format:  "%m/%d/%Y")
"08/02/2015"
```

Is there a way to do this in Ruby, so that

```
> I18n.localize(Date.strptime("ago 02, 2015", "%b %d, %Y"), format:  "%m/%d/%Y")
"08/02/2015"
```

Comment: are you looking for a fully language agnostic solution so it works for all or just for English?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you've already tried the following function which handles most scenarios for turning something into a DateTime object.

```
@date = Date.parse("ago 02, 2015")
```

Other than that you can try appending to the date constants so that it properly picks them up. Personally haven't tried this approach but might work for you?

```
require 'date'
Date::MONTHNAMES      = [nil] + %w( Enero Febrero Marzo Abril Mayo Junio Julio Agosto Septiembre Octubre Noviembre Diciembre )
Date::DAYNAMES        = %w( Lunes Martes Miércoles Jueves Viernes Sábado Domingo )
Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES = [nil] + %w( Ene Feb Mar Abr May Jun Jul Ago Sep Oct Nov Dic )
Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES   = %w( Lun Mar Mié Jue Vie Sáb Dom )
```

Lastly, have you considered using the [Chronic Gem](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic/) for date parsing? I believe it should handle cross language cases.

Comment: Tried Chronic, but it doesn't support i18n, either since it uses the ruby `Time` class.

Comment: Have you tried either of the other options I suggested?

Comment: `Date.parse` doesnt take non English month names.
The other didn't work either (atleast on Rails console), and ofcourse its overriding constants - bad practice

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute the Spanish words with English first. You can do it with `#gsub`, I18n yaml lookup, or a dictionary method, e.g.

```
dictionary = { "ago" => "Aug" }
date = "ago 02, 2015"
words = date.split
words[0] = dictionary[words[0]]
date = words.join(" ")  # "Aug 02, 2015"
```

Refactor it to take advantage of the power of OOP:

```
class DateDictionary 
  LOOKUP = { "ene" => "Jan", "ago" => "Aug" }

  def translate(date)
    words = date.split
    words[0] = LOOKUP[words[0]]
    date = words.join(" ")
  end
end

date = DateDictionary.new.translate("ago 02, 2015")  #  "Aug 02, 2015"
```

Comment: Not ideal, but this is nearly what I went with except no need for a dictionary itself. Since this is rails used the locale keys for months names